# Complete Mouse Scroll (Drag Scroll like but with no drag )

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouse

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find anything that suited to me.

I would like to do something like on this site:

http://fromtheroughmovie.com

I've looked into the js (800kb!), and from what I could see, it's using scrollTo to stealthily scroll towards elements depending on mouse position.

The closest script I could find was this : http://scripterlative.com/files/cursordivscroll.htm
But it scrolls only when towards the edges (I hacked it to try with a superior size but it stutters with Chrome).

Does anyone know how to do a complete mouse scroll (div is 4000px large, with 6 big divs positionned as absolute)? I tried a lot of things but this leads to nowhere for now.

If more information is needed, just ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this plugin?

http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

It's a pretty adaptable plugin with lots of scrolling functionality. It uses a function called 'scrollTo' which is maybe what you saw in that site's code?

Comment: Yeah Ive looked at it and tried, but the fact is that I can't seem to link it with the mouse position and movement (so bad with maths and such...).

Answer (score 0):

In your example code from scripterlative, you can adjust the scroll area to be from just around the edges. The example is set to 20% boundary:

```
new CursorDivScroll( 'userComment', 20, 10 );
```

You can change the second param to be 50 and see if that helps.

As for the original site you need to tidy the javascript up to see how it all works. The page content is loaded via AJAX. Search for function runTransition(page). This pulls in the 'home' page, after the intro. This content contains a more useful bit of javascript: http://www.fromtheroughmovie.com/js/main-home.js

From there, you can see how the cast images are scrolled:

```
<div id="home-mosaic">
    <ul>
        <li id="cast-image1">...</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

The javascript that does the hard work seems to be a jQuery animate:

```
$("#home-mosaic > ul > li").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find("div.home-mosaic-separation").animate({'width': (currentWidth*0.20) + 'px', 'left': (currentWidth*0.40) + 'px'}, 400); 
});

$("#home-mosaic > ul > li").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("div.home-mosaic-separation").css({'width': (currentWidth*0.02) + 'px', 'left': (currentWidth*0.49) + 'px'});
});
```

Hope that helps!